# Sharepoint list and external data source

Tags: xml, list, sharepoint, populate

I am new to SharePoint and I started reading on the subject. My question is simple : can I populate a SharePoint list with external data or this can only be made in Data Views ?

I currently have an XML file from witch data needs to be collected and added to a SharePoint list (every day for example).

What are my different possibilities ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819133.aspx

You need to define an external content type and use an external list that references it.

Comment: The thing is, I read all the articles about External Content Type and they are all related to Web Services of SQL Server connection. How would I create my own content type for getting data form a XML file and then link it to an external list ?

Comment: You would create an External Content Type based on a custom .NET assembly. Inside your assembly you can code anything you need to provide your entities - parsing the XML file, for example.