# Office 365 SharePoint site accessing data from external MySQL and/or PHP server

Tags: php, mysql, json, sharepoint, office365

I can't seem to find any other info on this topic anywhere on the interwebz.

SharePoint 365 seems so powerful, looks like an awesome solution for a whole bunch of business IT requirements.

But everything is in ASP and XML, but all my data is inside an external MySQL server, accessible through PHP pages which process and spit out JSON objects. This has worked nice and tidy for all my other apps so far.

How can I get my SharePoint site (which is basically HTML CSS and JavaScript, right?) to hit my PHP server (with HTTP GET or POST) to access my JSON data (and then process and display it however I like)?

I know AJAX can't hit external servers, so on my SharePoint site I'd need something equivalent to cURL perhaps... but with the functionality of AJAX?

Another possibility I'd avoid would be to create some kind of middle-man page/file/app in SharePoint which can process the data locally via AJAX, and send/receive data to/from the external PHP server. But this would all be in C# or ASP, ughhh surely there's an easier way?

**EDIT :**

Came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982179/sharepoint-list-and-external-data-source) regarding XML content, the best answer was to "create a custom .NET assembly" to parse the XML... I can't believe SharePoint with all its awesomeness wouldn't be able to handle external JSON content??

Comment: Your post regarding XML content is asking a very different question. He/She wants to load this their data into a list.  Your question is about just displaying it on the page.

Comment: Well the main thing I wanted to achieve was accessing the data and being able to display/manipulate it on the page, whether that be in my own HTML or turning my data into standard Office objects (if that would be easier) such as lists. And thanks for your answer, the REST service allows exactly what I was hoping SharePoint would allow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that SharePoint at it's heart is just ASP.net engine rendering HTML, JS and CSS down to the browser. For SP to access your data, you would need to expose the MySQL data via a REST service. This could be written in any language since it is a service.  It does not need to be C#, .net or ASP as all SP is doing is calling your endpoint and receiving the json data.  So no reason you could not use PHP for this.

Once you have the service, you can create a javascript file to call it using jQuery and the $.ajax() or getJSON() method to get the data.  You render the data onto the SharePoint page by adding the Script Webpart in the proper location.  Once added, click the Edit Snippet link on the script webpart and insert html with a reference to script file and a div to write the results.  There are many examples of how to do this type of request and parse the data on the web as it is not something specific to SharePoint.  Place the javascript file in the SharePoint site.  I typically put it in a custom folder in the _catalogs/masterpage library.

If you just need to display this external data on one page along side your SP data, like in a dashboard, this solution will work.  If the external data needs to interact with the SP data or you need to place it in multiple locations, then you may want to look into building a SharePoint App and you can use PHP to do this.  Here is a link to a sample project on GitHub.  https://github.com/OfficeDev/PHP-App-for-SharePoint